# How to deal with database changes in a MEAN application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, mongodb, mean-stack

I have struggled to find many resources on this online. I am developing an application that multiple users will be using at the same time. This means that one user may edit the database after another user has loaded the data from database. This means that this second user will not have an up to date view of the current state of the database. What is the best way to subscribe to database changes and deal with them. I am using a MEAN stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to develop a real time system where changes are reflected instantly upon changes in database, you need to make use of web sockets. Since you are using Node.js as backend, see [Socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Introduction)

A good resource for implementation can be found [here](https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/mean-socket-io-integration-tutorial/)

However, if you plan on implementing web sockets, you will have to make significant changes to both your Node.js and Angular code.

Another method (which I would not recommend) is to make periodic api calls for those views which you want to reflect real time changes. You can make use of `setInterval` for this